# how to add an object to a dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I need to create a JSON structure in the following format:

```
{
    "test": [
        {
            "mode": "2",
            "test": "test3"
        },
        {
            "mode": "1",
            "test": "test3"
        }
    ]
}
```

So whenever a JSON structure is created, it should be appended to the test element.

So initially I will have only the value:

```
string json=@"{""testfun"": [ {""mode"": ""2"", ""test"": ""test3"" }  ]}";

Dictionary<string, object> objtestnew2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

So how can I append when I get the next JSON structure to the existing dictionary element?

Answer (score 0):

Split your creation of the dictionary, and the deserialization into two different steps.

The first time the method is called it should see if the dictionary exists, and if it doesn't create one. If it does exist, then you can append the deserialized data to that dictionary.

Comment: Can you provide some samples?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the second dictionary then just merge it into the first one.  The simplest way to do it is a simple loop:

```
string json=@"{""testfun"": [ {""mode"": ""2"", ""test"": ""test3"" }  ]}";
Dictionary<string, object> dict = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

string json2=@"{""testfun"": [ {""mode"": ""1"", ""test"": ""test3"" }  ]}";
Dictionary<string, object> dict2 = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json2);

// loop through and update/add the items to the first dictionary
foreach(var item in dict2)
    dict1[item.Key] = item.Value;
```